# Convert from screen coordinates to an arbitrary scale

Tags: math, coordinates, scaling

I have some screen coordinates with a maximum Width of 650; so 0 - 650.
If i have some arbitrary scale say from 40 to 50, where 40 is the lowest point and 50 being the maximum. How do I convert say a screen coordinate of 430 relative to the scale?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: C# is the language but i think this is a more general question about the mathematical approach to solving the proportionality between these two scales: 0 - 650 and 40 - 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just maths:

```
static double ScreenToScaled(int screenMin, int screenMax, int scaledMin, int scaledMax, int screenValue)
{
    return (double)(screenValue - screenMin) / (double)(screenMax - screenMin) * (scaledMax - scaledMin) + scaledMin;
}
```

To see how it works, you can draw a chart of the screen value compared to the scaled value:
[image: chart]

(Apologies for the crudeness of the chart.)

With your values of the screen and scaled values, your conversion ends up as *y* = 0.01538 *x* + 40 where *x* is the screen value and *y* is the scaled value.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I just wanted to understand the math behind a linear transformation.

Comment: @YasinKhalil I added a graph showing the conversion from the screen value to the scaled value, if that helps you visualise what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

any other condition? based on what you gave us, it is just a linear mapping, which maps zero to 40 and 650 to 50.

with this in mind, each unit in new coordinate is equal to 65 in old one. Then 430/65=6.61, which means 430 is mapped to 40+6.61=46.61